# JSON Data not updating onChange()

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to do a html page that contains a table of countries, #of cases, and #of deaths that on page load displays all countries with select tag to view just a single countries data.
I'm having a problem with selecting options other than "All Countries" as if I select anything else, it doesn't return their data. Any help would be appreciated and I apologise in advance for my messy code

```js
let countriesJSON = null // this will be loaded once in ajaxListAllCountries() and used in listAllStatsInCountry()
let totalCountries = []

async function ajaxListAllCountries() {
  let url = `covidData.json` /* name of the JSON file */

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: `POST`,
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      },
    })

    updateWebpage(await response.json())
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Fetch failed: ', error)
  }



  /* use the fetched data to change the content of the webpage */
  function updateWebpage(jsonData) {
    let uniqueCountries = []
    let countryCases = []
    let countryDeaths = []
   

    // save the list of countries to local memory
    countriesJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData))

    let countries = jsonData.records.map(country =>
      ({
        Country: country.countriesAndTerritories,
        Cases: country.cases,
        Deaths: country.deaths
      })
    )
    // get the list of unique countries
    let countryNames = countries.map(country => country.Country)
    uniqueCountries = Array.from(new Set(countryNames)).sort()
    uniqueCountries.unshift("All Countries") // add "All Countries" to the front of the array
    const sumCountryCases = (countries, name) => {
      let total = 0
      countries.forEach(cases => {
        if (cases.Country === name) {
          total += cases.Cases
        }
      })
      return total
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < uniqueCountries.length; i++) {
      countryCases[i] = sumCountryCases(countries, uniqueCountries[i])
    }

    const sumCountryDeaths = (countries, name) => {
      let total = 0
      countries.forEach(deaths => {
        if (deaths.Country === name) {
          total += deaths.Deaths
        }
      })
      return total
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < uniqueCountries.length; i++) {
      countryDeaths[i] = sumCountryDeaths(countries, uniqueCountries[i])
    }


    for (let i = 0; i < uniqueCountries.length; i++) {
      totalCountries[i] = {
        Country: uniqueCountries[i],
        Cases: countryCases[i],
        Deaths: countryDeaths[i]
      }
    }


    console.log(totalCountries)
    console.log(uniqueCountries)

    let htmlString = `<select id="countries" onChange="listAllStatsInCountry(this.value)">`

    uniqueCountries.map(country => {
      if (country !== "") {
        htmlString += `<option value = "${country}">${country}</option>`
      }
    })

    htmlString += `</select>`
    document.getElementById('countries').innerHTML = htmlString

    // list all countries when the webpage opens
    listAllStatsInCountry("All Countries")
  }
}


function listAllStatsInCountry(country) {

  let statsInCountry = null;

  if (country === "All Countries") {
    statsInCountry = totalCountries

  } else if (country === "No Country") {
    statsInCountry = totalCountries.filter(country => country.Country === "")
  } else {
    statsInCountry = totalCountries.filter(country => country.Country === country)
  }

  let htmlString = `<table id="countriesTable"><tr><th>Country</th><th>Cases</th><th>Deaths</th></tr>`

  statsInCountry.map(country => {
    if (country.Country !== "All Countries") {
      htmlString += `<tr>
                           <td>${country.Country}</td>
                           <td>${country.Cases}</td>
                           <td>${country.Deaths}</td>
                      </tr>`
    }
  })


  htmlString += `</table><br>${statsInCountry.length} records found.`
  document.getElementById('allCountries').innerHTML = htmlString
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Global Covid-19 Statistics</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="ajaxListAllCountries()">
  <div id="countries"></div>
  <div id="allCountries"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

EDIT - Added a small bit of sample data from the json file

```js
{
  "records": [{
        "dateRep": "31/10/2020",
        "day": "31",
        "month": "10",
        "year": "2020",
        "cases": 157,
        "deaths": 4,
        "countriesAndTerritories": "Afghanistan",
        "geoId": "AF",
        "countryterritoryCode": "AFG",
        "popData2019": 38041757,
        "continentExp": "Asia",
        "Cumulative_number_for_14_days_of_COVID-19_cases_per_100000": "3.55398937"
      },
      {
        "dateRep": "17/05/2020",
        "day": "17",
        "month": "05",
        "year": "2020",
        "cases": 4,
        "deaths": 0,
        "countriesAndTerritories": "Estonia",
        "geoId": "EE",
        "countryterritoryCode": "EST",
        "popData2019": 1324820,
        "continentExp": "Europe",
        "Cumulative_number_for_14_days_of_COVID-19_cases_per_100000": "5.35921861"
      },
      {
        "dateRep": "16/01/2020",
        "day": "16",
        "month": "01",
        "year": "2020",
        "cases": 0,
        "deaths": 0,
        "countriesAndTerritories": "Estonia",
        "geoId": "EE",
        "countryterritoryCode": "EST",
        "popData2019": 1324820,
        "continentExp": "Europe",
        "Cumulative_number_for_14_days_of_COVID-19_cases_per_100000": "0"
      }
```

Comment: Is this "_I'm having a problem with selecting options other than "All Countries"_" a question about someone's API endpoint URLs not working? Shouldn't you ask the service provider, or read their documentation?

Comment: @RandyCasburn not using an API, I downloaded the data from https://data.europa.eu/euodp/en/data/dataset/covid-19-coronavirus-data and using that as a json file.

Comment: OK. We'll need to see a small sampling of the data from that file please.

Comment: @RandyCasburn updated post with some sample data, don't know if it'd be enough as the data has over 50k properties, some of the code is for removing dupelicate countries and adding their cases and deaths to a total value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `POST` request at all since you are simply `GET`ing a file. Your code works fine otherwise as demonstrated here: http://plnkr.co/edit/sAUdQx7dUckGAOrC

Edit in response to OP's comment:

Both filters are incorrect in the `listAllStatsInCountry()` function. Currently the array filters are written:

`statsInCountry = totalCountries.filter(country => country.Country === country)`

In both cases the use of variable `country` as the arrow function parameter shadows the outer scope's variable with the same name. So the filter doesn't ever find any thing. To fix this change those filters parameter names to something else like this:

`statsInCountry = totalCountries.filter(c => c.Country === country)`

That will work. The Plunkr has been updated.

**Change:**

```js
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: `POST`,
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  },
})
```

**To:**

```js
const response = await fetch(url);`
```

Comment: How would I update it, so that when selecting a country, it'd only display the data belonging to it?